# Connect Web Role to Web Site Role in the same windows azure solution

Tags: wcf, web-services, azure

We have a solution with a web role (WCF service role) and a WebSiteRole for a website we are building,

we are trying to connect the WebSiteRole to the WCFServiceRole with no success.
The Web reference comes out empty everytime while the service seems to be functioning properly.

We even tried making a new solution with an empty "DoWork" service to try to attach it , it comes out empty as well.

I used the svcutil to generate the proxy manually and add it to the project and that worked, but that's not the right way to connect to a service...

what am i doing wrong?

Update :
opened a new bug, hope they'll fix it
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790187/vs2012-add-service-reference-discover-services-in-solution-feature-creates-empty-proxy

Comment: so you're saying that you can't create the reference inside of Visual Studio(?), it's using svcutil under the covers, so what you did to get it working isn't a "wrong" way to do things.  You mention the service comes out empty - not sure what that means? Do you get an error in Add Service Reference...? or just no services found?  Is the metadata endpoint exposed?

Comment: to use "Add service reference" the project needs to be down, so - the service needs to be down. this is my take on why the reference comes out empty, when i say empty it means the auto generated proxy file comes out empty, the same file that comes out full when the service is running and i use svcutil manually from command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790187/vs2012-add-service-reference-discover-services-in-solution-feature-creates-empty-proxy

The types in the WCFRole and WebsiteRole are colliding.

Right click and the Service Reference -> Configure service reference -> Uncheck the "Reuse reference Types"

working like a charm now :)